# Laravel 5.7: How to recursively get an attribute from a nested Eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

First of all, I don't have any issues with setting up the relationship within the model.

I have a `WebGroup` model that can have unlimited parent `WebGroup`(s) as well as unlimited child `WebGroup`(s).

> Parent relationship:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsTo(WebGroup::class, 'pargroup1', 'webgroup')
        ->with('parent');
}
```

> Child relationship:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany(WebGroup::class, 'pargroup1', 'webgroup')
        ->with('children');
}
```

I can get a nested collection of all children for a given `WebGroup` via: `$webGroup->children`.

This gives me:

[image]

It's nested, it's unlimited. Fantastic. But now how can I recursively loop through that collection and recursively get a flatten array of a given attribute. For example each `WebGroup` model has a name attribute.

How to **recursively** get all names for a given collection of all `WebGroups` starting from parent, going down to all children down the rabbit hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to write this by myself…

```
private function getNestedChildrenByWebGroup(WebGroup $webGroup): Collection
{
    $data = collect([]);

    foreach ($webGroup->children as $child) {
        $data->push($child->webgroup);

        // If child has it's own children…
        if ($child->children instanceof Collection) {

            // Recursive call to all children of a child
            foreach ($child->children as $childWebGroup) {
                $this->getNestedChildrenByWebGroup($childWebGroup);
                $data->push($childWebGroup->webgroup);
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

**DB Structure**:

[image]

**Final result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer will only display 2 levels of children. But it will not display all descendants of parent.

Comment: You're absolutely wrong. Wondering if you're the one who downvoted my question? You define `children` relationship with `->with('children')` and then you grab children in recurrence and that will give you unlimited and nested results assuming your DB structure is correct. Double check your code and data. Cheers.

Comment: @Jearson notice how getNestedChildrenByWebGroup calls itself…

Comment: Nope I did not do that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this using appends variable. Get the children data using mutator like this,

```
public function getChildrenAttribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'parent_id')->get();
}
```

and then use the appends variable,

```
protected $appends = ['children'];
```

Then just call the function,

```
Category::find($id)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get all the childrens of the selected parent...

```
// Recursive function to get all children/sub-categories ids

function getRecursiveCategoryId($categoryId){ // Your Parent Category Id

    $children = [];
    $parentCategories = Category::where('parent_id', $categoryId)
                    ->latest()
                    ->select('id')
                    ->get();

    foreach ($parentCategories as $category) {

    $children[] = $category->id;


    $children[$category->id] = getRecursiveCategoryId($category->id,$children);
    
    }
                    
    return $children;                        
}

$arraySubCategoryIds = getRecursiveCategoryId($categoryId);

$arraySubCategoryIdss = Arr::flatten($arraySubCategoryIds);
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient. You make DB calls in a recursive calls. Also your method takes just one argument but then you call it with `getRecursiveCategoryId($category->id, $children)`. Very messy and inefficient. Check my accepted answer instead.

Comment: @MattKomarnicki so if i pass parent id in the parameter of your function will i get all the subcategoryIds ?

because i have to include this query to get all the subcategoryIds in the function:

 $parentCategories = Category::where('parent_id', $categoryId)
                                  ->latest()
                                  ->select('id')
                                  ->get();